# Notification sent by using firebase functions is not received on Android phone

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

My application is simply order app and I want admin get notification when new order is placed.
So to do that I send notification to device with token Id by using firebase functions.

```
'use-strict'
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('admin/{user_id}/notification/{notification_id}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    console.log("hehehehehehehehe");
    const user_id=context.params.user_id;

    const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database().ref(`admin/${user_id}`).once('value');

    //let tokensSnapshot;
    //let tokes;

    return Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise]).then(result => {
        //const registrationToken= result[0].tokenid.val();
        //console.log(registrationToken);

        const payload = {
          notification: {
            title: 'You have a new follower!',
            body: 'Yeni sifaris var',
          }
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice('fOCU86Rhhb4:APA91bHwJZInZYGp9cIDc7PyCw48QcEvvMOMuFepYcCTvkxlCJp8_Ieq1Ikwd9xNoU2rfTA9paRqCTLAuhUlZgF952AvpBstGdGRWMK8lCR2MHgHn6xzbvyxFEu-auRYexnPYmOnlTB1',payload).then((response) => {
            return console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
        }).catch((error) => {
            return console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        });

    });


});
```

Although I got the success response message in console log, my android phone couldn't get any notification.

```
Successfully sent message: { results: [ { messageId: '0:1542910779596746%095eb9af095eb9af' } ],
canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0,
failureCount: 0,
successCount: 1,
multicastId: 6551370257673400000 }
```

What is wrong with my code. I am new to firebase. I need your help.